Input impedance of linear blocks

If the input impedance of a linear block A is Rin1 and that of block B is Rin2 while the other terminal is grounded as shown, is there a way to find out Rin3 when A and B are in series?


is there a way to find out Rin3 when A and B are in series

There is no way of knowing this. I mean, a load on the output of block A may not have any effect on the input impedance of block A. Or, it may totally define the input impedance of block A. You can only calculate this if you know the impedance parameters. Example: -

Image from my answer here
